# Place widget in exact coordinate within image

Tags: image, flutter, zooming, image-scaling

In my application I have an image that can be zoomed in or out. I want to place another widget over the image and get them both scale at the same time.

The idea is first image has a window in it. I want to place 2nd image with in the window area.

I got the image scaling working with the following code. What I don't know is how to place another widget within exact area within the 1st image.

```
_buildWindowImage() {
    return Transform.scale(
      scale: _imageScale,
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: Image.asset(
        'assets/images/background/window_1.png',
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Can someone provide some help on this.

Comment: You can  use Stack or even Container and the image as the decorator and then in the child of the container add another image.

Comment: use `CustomPainter` where you will draw both images

Comment: I can use a stack to place the new image over the other image. But how do I adjust the exact position?

Comment: Is there another option other than CustomPainter? Ultimately i want to render a video instead of 2nd image.

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
_buildWindowImage() {
return Transform.scale(
      scale: _imageScale,
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage(
              'assets/images/background/window_1.png',
            ),
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
          ),
        ),
        child: Center(_put_another_widget_here),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to place the 2nd image at the center. I need a way to place it in exact location.

Comment: then maybe you can use Stack then lay the children on each other or use Positioned to set the coordinates.